# Syntax for publication list with full authors

Tags: r

I’m using the Vitae package to build my CV, and finding it super useful. BUT I’m having trouble pulling my publications list from the web. The scholar package returns incomplete author lists when the author lists are long, and I'm not having success using the get_complete_authors command to correct that. I need the list of authors to be complete in the data frame so that I can use it with the vitae structure. The rorcid package looks great but is rather inscrutable for a newbie like me (it looks like it uses some kind of nested list which is a bit terrifying)! Could anyone share syntax for pulling publication history from orcid, please? It would be ideal to have suitable syntax that I could just adapt with my own orcID to work for me! Alternatively, syntax for pulling publication history from scholar with COMPLETE author lists would also work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Scholar allows you to export your own citations to a bibtex file. From your own profile page, you're able to select any/all of your citations and use the "Export" option to generate the appropriate `.bib` file. This `.bib` file can then be used with `vitae::bibliography_entries()` to add citations to your CV.

https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/citations.html#questions

Using the `scholar` package can help automate this, but as you've experienced it has limitations. This is largely because Google does not provide an API to Google Scholar, and so the package scrapes data from search results. The below code will replace incomplete authors with a complete list using `scholar::get_complete_authors()`, however if you have many citations with many authors you will encounter rate limiting issues.

```r
scholar_id <- "<YOUR ID>"
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(scholar)
pubs <- scholar::get_publications(id = scholar_id)
pubs %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    author = case_when(
      str_ends(author, "\\.\\.\\.") ~ get_complete_authors(id = scholar_id, pubid = pubid),
      TRUE ~ author
    )
  )
```

---

To obtain publications from ORCID, you can use the `rorcid::orcid_citations()` function. By default it will provide the citations in a bibtex format, which can be saved and used with:

```r
pubs <- rorcid::orcid_citations("0000-0002-2140-5352")
writeLines(pubs$citation, "publications.bib")
bibliography_entries("publications.bib")
```

Comment: This was really helpful @Mitchell, thank you. Interestingly, I learned that Google was somehow blocking my IP address (presumably I put in too many requests for data while I was figuring out all the syntax) so I had to use my phone's hotspot to get it to work again! Also, the rorcid option wouldn't play nicely for me due to some biber conflict with which my level of insight is not compatible with fixing. But I'm happy that the scholar option is up and running now; thanks ever so much.